# Azure signin logs not sent to log analytics even after configuring diagnostics settings

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics, azure-service-principal, azure-alerts

I am unable to send the logs to the log analytics workspace in order to monitor the service principal sign in logs.

I have a service principal in azure. I want to send its signin logs to a log analytics workspace in order to monitor and later setup alerts on them. But when I follow these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/howto-integrate-activity-logs-with-azure-monitor-logs I cannot see any logs in my log analytics workspace.

Comment: Could you confirm whether your requirement is to send these logs to log analytics workspace? https://i.imgur.com/eUYELZM.png

Comment: After configuring the diagnostic setting, did you wait for 15 minutes as mentioned in that document?

Comment: Yes, I want to send those logs to logs analytics workspace. Yes, I did wait for 15 min and also signed in again as mentioned in the docs. I can see the user sign in logs in the log analytics but no service principal sign in logs.

Comment: What check boxes you selected while creating diagnostic setting?

Comment: I selected all of these checkboxes - https://imgur.com/a/blm3tws. Also, this is the query I am running 
AADServicePrincipalSignInLogs
| count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can finally see the logs in the log analytics. Had to follow these steps only https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/howto-integrate-activity-logs-with-azure-monitor-logs but instead of 15 min I had to wait for ~2 hours for the logs to be visible.

Steps to direct service principal logs to the log analytics workspace.
Prerequisites:

1. Have a log analytics workspace setup
2. Should have at least `Security Administrator` role assigned.

Steps, from the document:

> 1. Sign in to the Microsoft Entra admin center as at least a Security Administrator.
> 2. Browse to Identity > Monitoring & health > Diagnostic settings. You can also select Export Settings from either the Audit Logs or Sign-ins page.
> 3. Select + Add diagnostic setting to create a new integration or select Edit setting for an existing integration.
> 4. Enter a Diagnostic setting name. If you're editing an existing integration, you can't change the name.
> 5. Select the log categories that you want to stream. (In my case I had to select the `ServicePrincipalSignInLogs` category)
> 6. Under Destination Details select the Send to Log Analytics workspace check box.
> 7. Select the appropriate Subscription and Log Analytics workspace from the menus.
> 8. Select the Save button.

As per the doc, we should see the logs getting streamed in the workspace after about ~15 min but it might take longer as well.